# Frobenius Auto need not be an automorphism if F is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm trying to find an example to show the map $\sigma_p : F \rightarrow F$ given by $\sigma_p(a)=a^p$ for $a\in F$ need not be an automorphism in the case that F is infinite. I'm lost as to where to start. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5):

Simply pick any field where not all elements are $p$th powers.

For example, let $F=\mathbb F_P(t)$, the field of rational functions on the variabe $t$ with coefficients in the prime field $\mathbb F_p$. You should have no problem showing that $t\in F$ is not a $p$th power.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58424/example-of-infinite-field-of-characteristic-p-neq-0/58425#58425) is a discussion of two standard examples of infinite fields of characteristic $p$. One of them is a counterexample, and the other is not. Try to work out for yourself which is which.

When you are done, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/how-to-prove-that-the-frobenius-homomorphism-is-surjective/91736#91736) for further discussion about the Frobenius map and its bijectivity (or lack thereof).