# How do I prove this field homomorphism is an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> The question is as follows. Let $F$ be a finite field with unit $1$ not equal to zero. Let the function $f: F \to F$ be given by $f(x) = x^3$, where the $\operatorname{char}(F) = 3$. Prove it is a ring isomorphism.

I can prove it is a ring homomorphism by showing $f(xy) = (xy)^3 = x^3y^3 = f(x)f(y)$ by commutativity. Similarly, since the characteristic is three,

$$(x+y)^3 = x^3 + y^3$$

$$f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$$

$$f(1) = 1,\ \ \textrm{and}\ \  f(0) = 0$$

Now, how do I show $f$ is a bijection?

Comment: Fields have $1\neq 0$ by definition; there's no need to assume it.

Comment: Zev, so you're saying the trivial ring {0} isn't a field?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

That homomorphism is necessarily injective, but **not** necessarily surjective. For example, the field $F=\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ has characteristic $3$, and the homomorphism $\varphi:F\to F$ defined by $\varphi(a)=a^3$ for all $a\in F$ is not surjective because there is no $a\in F$ with $\varphi(a)=t$.

For a more in-depth analysis, take a look at my answer on the thread *[How to prove that the Frobenius homomorphism is surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91688/264)*

Comment: Good point. I edited to refer to a finite field.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not an isomorphism in general, as Zev explained. But in the case that $F$ is finite it is:

It is a homomorphism, as you have shown, and any homomorphism of fields is injective. But also, any injective function from a finite set to itself is a bijection, hence $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: To show f is injective, I can say (given nonzero a,b) f(a) = f(b) <==> f(a)(f(b))^-1 = 1 <==> f(a)f(b^-1) = 1 <==> f(ab^-1) = 1 <==> ab^-1 = 1 <==> a = b. The reason f is a field is important is because b must have inverse.

Comment: Now, how do I show f is a surjection? That is, given a in F, how do i show there is b in F, such that a = b^3?

Comment: You haven't actually shown $f$ is injective in the comment. To do that it suffices to show ker $f = \{0\}$. So, suppose $f(a)=0$. This means that $a^3=0$, so that $a=0$ (fields are domains), and thus ker $f = \{0\}$. To show that $f$ is surjective, take another look at my answer - $f$ is an injective function from a finite set to itself. This means that it is also surjective.

Comment: Thanks Noah, your response was very helpful!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why did my argument in the comment fail to show injectivity? Where was the error?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, you didn't justify the step $f(ab^{-1})=1 \iff ab^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score -1):

To get started, $\ker(f)$ is an ideal in the ring $F$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What are the ideals present in a field?  Yes, it settles the question of injectivity.  I am offering a substantial hint, and I trying to avoid giving away the answer and spoiling things for the  OP.

Comment: I believe this is better suited as a comment.

Comment: Since ker(f) is an ideal, f/ker(f) is isomorphic to f(F). The kernel is trivial by injectivity, so f(F) is isomorphic to f. Thus f(F) = F, proving surjectivity?