# $x\mapsto x^p$ with $\operatorname{char}(F)=p>0$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: ring-homomorphism, positive-characteristic

Let a field $F$ with $\operatorname{char}(F)=p>0$. Let a map $f:F\to F$ defined be $x\mapsto x^p$. Show that $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

Obviousely $0\mapsto 0$ and $(xy)^p=x^py^p$. How can I show $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$? I need to show here for any $0<i<p$ $0=x^iy^{p-i}$.

Comment: Use the binomial expansion for $(x+y)^p$.

Comment: I did, now I need to show $0=x^iy^{p-i}$ but I'm not sure how to show that. @Lubin

Comment: It doesn’t look to me as if you expanded correctly: $(x+y)^5=x^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$

Comment: You right, I need to show $0=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i}x^iy^{p-i}$ and I would like for some help, thanks! @Lubin

Comment: Write out $\binom p i$. You have a formula involving factorials, right?

Comment: Ohh now I see it, $p|\binom{p}{i}$ thus $\binom{p}{i}_F=0_F$. Thnks! @Lubin

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/how-to-prove-that-the-frobenius-endomorphism-is-surjective

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that the binomial theorem holds in any commutative ring with unit, though some of the terms may drop out in the event the ring is of finite, prime characteristic.  To wit:

$(x + y)^2 = (x + y)(x + y)$
$= x(x + y) + y(x + y) = x^2 + xy + yx + y^2 = x^2 + xy + xy + y^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2; \tag 1$

$(x + y)^3 = (x + y)(x + y)^2 = (x + y)(x^2 + 2xy + y^2) = x(x^2 + 2xy + y^2) + y(x^2 + 2xy + y^2)$
$= x^3 + 2x^2y + xy^2 + yx^2 + 2xy^2 + y^3 = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3; \tag 2$

$(x + y)^4 = (x + y)(x + y)^3 = (x + y)(x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3)$
$= x(x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3) + y(x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3)$
$= x^4 + 3x^3y + 3x^2y^2 + xy^3 + yx^3 + 3x^2y^2 + 3xy^3 + y^4$
$= x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4; \tag 3$

$(x + y)^5 = (x + y)(x + y)^4 = (x + y)(x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4)$
$= x( x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4) + y(x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4)$
$= x^5 + 4x^4y + 6x^3y^2 + 4x^2y^3 + xy^4 + yx^4 + 4x^3y^2 + 6x^2y^3 + 4xy^4 + y^5$
$= x^5 + 5x^4y + 10x^3y^2 + 10x^2y^3 + 5xy^4 + y^5; \tag 4$

careful scrutiny of (1)-(4) reveals that for every case of prime exponent, ***viz.*** $n = 2, 3, 5$, $n$ divides every coefficient occurring in the binomial expansion save those of $x^n$ and $y^n$, which are themselves equal to $1$; this suggests we examine the binomial coefficents

$\begin{pmatrix} p \\ k \end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{p!}{k!(p - k)!}, \; 0 \le k \le p, \; \text{a prime}, \tag 5$

since, as is well-known for any $n \in \Bbb N$ we have

$(x + y)^n = \displaystyle \sum_0^n\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} x^{n - k}y^k = \displaystyle \sum_0^n \dfrac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}x^{n - k}y^k; \tag 6$

if we write

$\dfrac{p!}{k!(p - k)!} = \dfrac{p(p - 1)(p - 2) \ldots (p - k + 1)}{k!}, \; p \in \Bbb P, \tag 7$

we observe that for $1 \le k \le p - 1$, $p$ and $k!$ have no factor greater than $1$ in common, since $p$ is prime and with $k < p$,

$k! = k(k - 1)(k - 2) \ldots (1) \tag 8$

has no factor divisible by $p$; it follows then that $p \in \Bbb P$ implies

$p \mid \dfrac{p!}{k!(p - k)!}, \; 1 \le k \le p - 1; \tag 9$

returning then to (6) with $n = p$ we see that, in a ring of characteristic $p \in \Bbb P$,

$(x + y)^p = x^p + y^p; \tag{10}$

now having

$(xy)^p = x^py^p \tag{11}$

already at our disposal, (10) allows us to conclude that the map

$x \to x^p \tag{12}$

is in fact a ring homomorphism in characteristic $p$; thus a field homomorphism in characteristic $p \in \Bbb P$ as well.  $OE\Delta$.

Comment: A one-sentence proof!

Comment: @darijgrinberg  Indeed; I hadn't noticed.  One pretty long sentence.  It has to do with the inordinate love affair 'twixt mathematicians and semicolons!  Cheers!

Comment: I could prove that it was a homomorphism. But, my question came with an additional part asking whether it's an isomorphism as well. Can you help me a little on that please... I'm pretty sure, the answer is no, but I can't find a counterexample.