# Finding an example of $\sigma:F\rightarrow F; a\mapsto a^p$ not surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have the following question,

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p\neq 0$. Find an example where the homomorphism 
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \sigma :  &F\rightarrow F\\
> & a\mapsto a^p
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   is not surjective.

Trying a lot of things I found that if I take $a\in Ker(\sigma)$ then, $a^p=0 \Rightarrow a^{p-1}a=0$, so $a$ would be a zero divisor and that contradicts $F$ being a field. So $\sigma$ is injective. Then if $F$ is finite, $F$ is an automorphism! That gives me a hint, I must find an infinite field of characteristic $p>0$.

The only infinite field in that fashion that I know is $\mathbb{Z}_p(x)=\{\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}| \ p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x], q(x)\neq0\}$, so I was trying to prove $\sigma$ is not surjective.

If I take $a=p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\subset\mathbb{Z}_2(x)$ then, $\sigma(p(x))=p(x)^2$ and therefore, $$deg(\sigma(p(x)))=2deg(p(x))$$

So all the images of $\sigma$ would have even degree (for $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$), but I'm not sure if I can generalize that for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p(x)$. I'm not sure about what's the degree of $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ or if I'm going in the right way.

---

Any help would be awesome. Or any other example for this case (since I only know one case of infinite fields of possitive characteristic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question was marked as duplicate but I can't understand the answer posted. What can I do?

Comment: Take $F=\Bbb F_p(t)$ and read another duplicate, i.e., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/how-to-prove-that-the-frobenius-endomorphism-is-surjective). I think, more details than Zev's answer has is impossible. He explains in detail why $t$ is not contained in the range.

Comment: Wow! What an amazing and detailed answer. Thanks! Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Good dupe work.